# Airflow Kubernetes executor - multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I have a Kubernetes cluster with multiple namespaces. A namespace per each client, that's how we separate clients' data.

I want to run a single airflow cluster containing DAGs per client. But **is there a way to use the Kubernetes executor so that it will execute each task on a different namespace based on some parameter?** 
I noticed the Kubernetes executor has only one namespace parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes does not support multiple namespaces for the `--namespace` argument currently. More info about this is [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52326) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71032).

I think a single operation across multiple namespaces will be complex, and may produce inconsistent results and race conditions.

`kubectl get --all-namespaces` gets resources from all namespaces.

An operation can be repeatedly run in each namespace serially in a programmatic way as follows:

```
kubectl get ns -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -n 1 -I % kubectl get pods -n=%

kubectl get ns -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}' | xargs -n 1 -I % kubectl get all -n=%
```

Comment: I was asking specifically about airflow kubernetes executor. Every operation should run in a single namespace I am looking for a way to configure it

Comment: @LiorH did you find a solution for this?